# Whats the difference between a Fujitsu Lifebook T902 battery and a Fujitsu Lifebook AH531 battery?

Tags: windows-10, battery, desktop-computer

My Fujitsu Lifebook T902’s battery has gone bad, and I'm trying to get a new one.

The Fujitsu Lifebook AH531  battery is $50 cheaper than a Fujitsu Lifebook T90 battery, so would it make a difference if I got the Fujitsu Lifebook AH531?

I'm trying not to murder my laptop.

Comment: One is an apple. The other is an orange. But both are roundish fruit. I know that might sound snarky, but one battery for one manufacturer’s product doesn’t inherently mean it is a battery that will work with another manufacturer’s product. You need to get the battery that your device needs and not speculate on why one might be cheaper… Unless you 100% explicitly know they would work in both systems.

Answer (score 2):

Your battery is part of a [Fujitsu safety recall program](https://www.fujitsu.com/us/support/products/computing/notebooks/battery-recall/2018.html) which I found so you should be able to contact the manufacturer if you still have warranty.

If you need a new battery I recommend [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DWYM7M5). Since it has a similar rating to your’s.

Off-brand batteries can cause damage if they don’t have the right voltage so I recommend you get the official battery it is worth spending a little more to not have damage to the laptop in the end.

Your battery model is Fujitsu FPCBP360 you can google it

Fujitsu Lifebook AH531 battery wouldn't fit your Laptop since it doesn’t have the same shape and latching mechanism also it looks like it doesn’t fit the connector on motherboard either.